# Connect password protected access file

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I want to connect with password protected access file. with below coding, I am getting an error as "Incorrect password" but when I open it manually with the same password, its open. Do I get to make any changes in database setting.

```
Dim Acon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset

With Acon
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + "U:\scratch\OK.accdb"
    .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = "123"
    .Open
 End With
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you will get that problem. To sort it, follow the steps exactly as I tell you

1. Close your database
2. From Access, click on **File|Open** and then open your database as `Exclusive`
   [image]
3. Decrypt the database from the **File** menu

   [image]
4. Click on **File|Options|Client Settings** and navigate to the end and select the options shown below
   [image]
5. Encrypt your database after you click `OK` in the above screen.
6. Close the database and then try the code

**Code I used for testing**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Acon As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    With Acon
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Database3.accdb"
        .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = "test"
        .Open
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know what the difference is between the new encryption and the legacy encryption. Does reverting to the old method make it less secure?